# Could you run Ethereum to behave like a faster Bitcoin?

Tags: bitcoin, nodes

Without Smart Contracts. Would that system scale better and have less technical hustles than Bitcoin itself?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes besides that it uses accounts instead of transactions saved in the blockchain and some other technical details you can run Ethereum like Bitcoin. And it would have faster block time confirmations and smaller block chain sizes.